# Ansible playbook to execute Oracle script

Tags: oracle, ansible, sqlplus

I am attempting to run a playbook to execute Oracle Scripts.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
- tasks: 
   - set_fact:
        execute_command: "sqlplus {{ Oracle_Username }}/{{ Oracle_Password }} @{{ sqlfile.sql }}"

   - name: Get Object_details 
     shell: "echo exit | {{ execute_command }} >> ./Oracle_Output.csv"
     environment:
        ORACLE_HOME: "{{ Oracle_DBServer }}"
        ORACLE_SID: "{{ Oracle_SID }}"
```

I have declared all the variables in vars.When I execute it , am getting error "set_fact is not valid attribute for a play" .
Which is the best way to run SQL script using Ansible?  I have to declare all the connection details in variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
- tasks:
   - name: Get Object_details 
     shell: echo exit |sqlplus "{{ oracle_username }}/ {{ oracle_pwd}} @(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host={{ oracle_hostname }} )(Port={{ oracle_port }}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME= {{ service_name }})))"@sqlfile.sql;
```

With the above code , we will be directly able to connect to Oracle Host and execute sql script. If the Oracle Environment variables are not defined by default, we can set that too in the playbook task itself. Below is the example for that :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
- tasks:
   - name: Get Object_details 
     shell: echo exit |sqlplus "{{ oracle_username }}/ {{ oracle_pwd}} @(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host={{ oracle_hostname }} )(Port={{ oracle_port }}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME= {{ service_name }})))"@sqlfile.sql;
     environment:
          ORACLE_HOME: <<Oracle Home path >>
          PATH: << bin path >>
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH: << lib path >>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare `tasks` section:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
- tasks:
    - set_fact:
        execute_command: "sqlplus {{ Oracle_Username }}/{{ Oracle_Password }} @{{ sqlfile.sql }}"

    - name: Get Object_details 
      shell: "echo exit | {{ execute_command }} >> ./Oracle_Output.csv"
      environment:
        ORACLE_HOME: "{{ Oracle_DBServer }}"
        ORACLE_SID: "{{ Oracle_SID }}"
```

P.S. and I'm not aware of `wait` attribute for tasks.

Comment: I used Ansible roles and this yml script is inside tasks. So no need to mention tasks section

Comment: The error message suggests that you run this yml script as playbook. And if this is a main.yml inside role tasks, `hosts` is not allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export ORACLE_HOME first. Then you can call sqlplus from oracle's bin folder.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
- tasks:
    - name: Execute table.sql using sqlplus 
      shell: $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s username/password@connect @table.sql
      environment:
        ORACLE_HOME: "{{oracle_home_path}}"
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "{{ld_library_path}}"
        PATH: "{{bin_path}}"
      args:
        chdir: "{{sql_path}}" 
      become: true
      become_method: su
      become_user: oracle
```